# Почему Visual Studio ругается на fseek(f,-sizeof(char),SEEK_CUR)

Tags: c++, c, файлы

Мне нужно было перенести указатель файла на один символ назад. Поэтому я использовал `fseek(f,-sizeof(char),SEEK_CUR);`. И на gcc всё нормально компилировалось, потом я перенёс этот код на Visual Studio 2017 и в нём такая запись уже не компилируется и проект не запускается, хотя красной волнистой линией не подчёркивается.

Выдаёт ошибку `применение унарного минуса к типу без знака;результат оставлен без изменения`.
Поэтому у меня вопрос: как можно заставить такую запись работать, ведь gcc не ругался. Или как можно по-другому перенести указатель файла на одну позицию назад?

Comment: Это всего лишь предупреждение. Можно просто его игнорировать, можно выполнить приведение наподобие `-int(sizeof(char))` (`-(int)sizeof(char)` в C) или - чтоб строго соответствовать духу и букве C++ - `-static_cast<int>(sizeof(char))`.

Comment: @Harry, помогло, написали бы тоже как ответ:)

Comment: Без вопросов :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Результат `sizeof` имеет беззнаковый тип. Применение унарного `-` к беззнаковому значению не дает отрицательного значения, а дает "завернутое" положительное значение. `-sizeof(char)` - это `SIZE_MAX`, огромное положительное значение. Об этом вам и говорит компилятор.

Прекратите извращаться с `sizeof`  и просто напишите `-1`. Если вы хотите все таки оставить `sizeof`, то его результат нужно привести к знаковому типу ДО применения унарного `-`: `-(long int) sizeof(char)` (не  `(long int) -sizeof(char)`).

Имейте в виду, однако, что такой способ позиционирования не обязан поддерживаться в текстовых потоках.

Comment: спасибо,  осознал

Answer (score 2):

Это всего лишь предупреждение. 
Можно просто его игнорировать, можно выполнить приведение наподобие `-int(sizeof(char))`
 (`-(int)sizeof(char)` в C) или - чтоб строго соответствовать духу и букве C++ - как

```
-static_cast<int>(sizeof(char))
```