# Как правильно вернуть указатель файла на позицию назад?

Tags: c, файлы

Когда я делал парсинг, я использовал `fseek(f, -1, SEEK_CUR);`,чтобы возвращаться на позицию назад.И в Ubuntu на gcc всё работало,но теперь в Windows на Visual Studio он работает не так как я планировал.

В [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/970453/258486) ответе , мне подсказали, что "что такой способ позиционирования не обязан поддерживаться в текстовых потоках.". Как же тогда верно вернуться на позицию в файле назад (или на указанное количество шагов(байт) назад). Просто иначе придётся переделывать парсинг.

Comment: А зачем вам текстовый поток? Тем более, раз вы используете `fseek`, то у вас нормальные файловые операции, и никаких текстовых потоков. Что у вас не работает-то? Приведите текст программы с проблемой, так сложно предполагать где у вас ошибка. Поскольку в Windows позиционирование работает нормально, дело явно в вашем коде.

Comment: imho [ungetc()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ungetc) для возврате на один `char` обязан работать для `FILE *` независимо от типа  объекта (файл, pipe, tty и т.п.)

Comment: @avp, в Windows `FILE` вроде только для файлов (точно не помню, использование пайпов под вин большая экзотика), но с файлами `ungetc` работает нормально. Насчет возврата на несколько символов у `ungetc` есть нюансы, но тут надо просто использовать нормальные файловые операции и не связываться с символьным вводом.

Comment: @freim, `"в Windows FILE вроде только для файлов"` -- это вряд ли... Например, `stdin` даже в винде  без сомнения `FILE *`, однако обычно он связан не с файлом (конечно, если у вас нет привычки перенаправлять вход запускаемой программы на файл) Что касается возврата на несколько символов, то это обычно работает в glibc (и наверное будет в среде MinGW), но вообще-то не обязательно в POSIX

Comment: @avp,а как пользоваться ungetc(), если я читаю из файла и хочу "вернуть прочитанное " назад в файл, то есть у меня нет буфферной int переменной

Comment: @Elvin, когда парсите посимвольно и принимаете решение по последнему считанному из файла символу  `int  c; ... while((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) { ... }`, и читаете внутри `while` еще символы (тоже `c = fgetc(file)`), а в какой-то момент понимаете, что последний прочитанный символ должен относиться к другой лексеме, то пишете `ungetc(c, file)` и переходите к началу `while` / Обычно для рекурсивного спуска как-то так.

Comment: @avp, вообще-то рекурсивный спуск - это синтаксический анализатор, и он работает с лексемами, а не с символами. Лексический анализатор - это обычный конечный автомат, и ему возвращаться в потоке не нужно. То есть для нормально построенного сканера `ungetc` вообще ни к чему.

Comment: @freim, все зависит от определенных в вашем языке лексем. Например, если у вас будет лексема `real_number`, то ungetc для ее распознавания  нужен, если же вы начинаете различать типы числовых констант на уровне синтаксического анализа (есть только лексема `unsigned_integer`), то можно и без него. Аналогично для символов, строк и т.п. На практике, когда пишете простой анализатор вручную (без lex/yacc) лексический и синтаксический анализ вообще частично перемешиваются (ну, логика разбора такая, что подобный подход упрощает весь код) и без возврата на шаг все это не сложится.