# Подскажите алгоритм для парсинга

Tags: c, алгоритм, файлы

У меня возник вопрос о том, как сделать правильно парсинг.
Вот есть такое сообщение:

```
26.09.2014 29.04.2014 18:37:33 msg1.msg1.msg1.msg1.
14.06.2004 01.06.2003 00:42:16 msg2.msg2.msg2.msg2.
19.02.2012 22.08.2007 07:42:48 msg3.msg3.msg3.msg3.
02.10.2002 12.02.2010 17:05:54 msg4.msg4.msg4.msg4.


15.01.2010 08.10.2013 20:54:09 msg5.msg5.msg5.msg5.

13.11.2002 01.01.2015 14:21:59 msg6.msg6.msg6.msg6.
22.05.2010 31.05.2018 08:55:57 msg7.msg7.msg7.msg7.
31.01.2001 21.10.2017 22:29:26 msg8.msg8.msg8.msg8.
07.11.2007 13.11.2014 06:51:24 msg9.msg9.msg9.msg9.
29.10.2014 21.07.2020 17:53:42 msg10.msg10.msg10.msg10.


01.09.2002 19.01.2006 10:45:14 msg11.msg11.msg11.msg11.
27.08.2005 13.02.2011 19:10:31 msg12.msg12.msg12.msg12.
05.09.2017 21.04.2005 22:03:18 msg13.msg13.msg13.msg13.
11.12.2004 20.08.2010 21:59:42 msg14.msg14.msg14.msg14.
```

Мне нужно вытащить отсюда две даты числа, два месяца, два года, время и сам текст.Пустые строки должны игнорироваться. Текст может быть записан немного хитро, то есть,например,содержать пробел в конце. Мой старый алгоритм, чтобы понимать когда заканчивался текст текущего сообщения и начала дат следующего, заходил на пару символов на другое сообщение(например, на 14. от даты 14.06.2004 ) , понимал , что это другое сообщение и возвращал указатель файла на эти три лишние шага назад - делал это так:

```
fseek(f, -(int)sizeof(char), SEEK_CUR);
fseek(f, -(int)sizeof(char), SEEK_CUR);
fseek(f, -(int)sizeof(char), SEEK_CUR);
```

Но т.к код перенёс с Ubuntu на Windows (уже спрашивал [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/970453/258486) и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/975399/258486)), этот трюк с возвратом работать перестал. Можете описать более лучший алгоритм для парсинга?

Comment: Ну, по крайней мере в прошлом вопросе не надо было так торжественно именовать это парсингом. Алгоритм прост. Считаете словом все, что не содержит пробелов. Читаете 4 слова, пока не встретится '\n'. Смотрите сколько прочли. Если 0 --- пустая строка, все ОК. Если меньше 4-х - ошибка формата. Собственно, все. Слово-то произвольной длины прочесть сможете?

Answer (score 0):

> как сделать правильно парсинг

```
 char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim);
```

Смотрим *man 3 strtok*:

> Функция  *strtok()*  разделяет строку на последовательность нуля или
>   более непустых токенов. При первом вызове strtok()  анализируемую 
>   строку  нужно  указывать  в  аргументе  str.  В  каждом последующем
>   вызове, в котором анализируется эта же строка, значение str должно
>   быть NULL.
>
> В аргументе delim задаётся набор байт, которые считаются разделителями
>   токенов в анализируемой строке. Вызывающий может указывать разные
>   строки в delim в последующих вызовах при анализе той же строки.
>
> Каждый  вызов  *strtok()*  возвращает  указатель на строку,
>   завершающуюся null, которая содержит следующий токен. Эта строка не
>   включает байт-разделитель. Если больше токенов нет, то *strtok()*
>   возвращает NULL.